# NHibernate Criteria Restriction vs Expression

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

If I search for NHibernate Criteria API query examples in internet there are examples that use Restrictions and others use Expression. What are the differences between those two?

For example:

```
posts = session.CreateCriteria<Post>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Id", 1))
    .List<Post>();

posts = session.CreateCriteria<Post>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 1))
    .List<Post>();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think Restrictions were released in NH2 and is now the favoured way.

According to Resharper whenever I use Expression I get a hint to say `Access to a static member of a type via a derived type`

Also [according to this post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/03/31/NHibernate-2.0-Alpha-is-out.aspx) by Ayende:-

> Prefer to use the Restrictions instead
>   of the Expression class for defining
>   Criteria queries.

Answer (score 14):

In the source code for `namespace NHibernate.Criterion.Expression` is says that "This class is semi-deprecated use Restrictions"

Answer (score 1):

Expression inherits from Restrictions but it is recommended to use Restrictions. Expression is apparently deprecated.

According to [Ayende (old post about NH 2.0)](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/03/31/NHibernate-2.0-Alpha-is-out.aspx#22282), documentation will usually refer to Restrictions.